# Protect Deployments from manual deletion

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

We have an Azure-Kubernetes and use a helm chart to manage a list of deployments.

I would like to somehow block manual removal of the deployments. Deletion of the pods is fine, actually wanted to be able to "restart" the services inside to clean up cache and so on.

I'm sorry for the short question, am searching for a while but so far found nothing promising.

Comment: you can use the RBAC rule to setup access across the users and you can use same, so users wont be having access to delete deployment while you can list pods and delete pod

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the RBAC into the K8s cluster.

Role for the **deployment** manager

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: deployment-manager
rules:
- apiGroups: ["*"]
  resources: ["deployments", "replicasets", "pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]
```

**Role** for **developer**

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: developer
rules:
- apiGroups: ["", "extensions", "apps"]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]
```

**Role binding deployment manager**

```
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: deployment-manager-binding
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: admin
  apiGroup: ""
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: deployment-manager
  apiGroup: ""
```

**Role binding developer**

```
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: developer-manager-binding
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: dev
  apiGroup: ""
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: developer
  apiGroup: ""
```

You can create two new **K8s** contexts and using that check

```
kubectl --context=dev-context get pods
```

You can read more at : https://docs.bitnami.com/tutorials/configure-rbac-in-your-kubernetes-cluster/